# Why wordpress wp-config.php file automatically rewritten?

Tags: php, wordpress

i have developed a WordPress site, today made it live..
when the site was in test server its working fine. When i uploaded through FTP to the live server for sometime its works fine then after few minutes i saw Error in establish in database connection. The `wp-config.php` file rewrites the old file. The username, database name and password rewrites same as in the test server.

I have tried following steps
1. Rename the database information
2. Delete the `wp-config.php` files but automatically created the test server config file.
3. Change the `wp-load.php` files but again it changes to default data.

Comment: Sounds more like your setup is auto-syncing the files and replacing wp-config, WordPress does not write to wp-config ever, and wp-load should not be altered in any way...

Comment: It would be interesting to see what new information is being written in the wp-config file. Maybe Wordpress is getting confused and still thinks it's going through the installation process? That's the only time the config file is created

Comment: Delete cache and temp internet files and retry

Comment: i have deleted all the files and folder through ftp, but it automatically creates all files and folders after few minutes.